# How to restart webdriver Selenium when script is finished

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am experimenting with Selenium and I have a code that load some URL and click on the button, so far my code looks like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://example.org/"
driver.get(url)
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cool-button")
button.click()
driver.quit()
```

This code works as expected, but what am trying to achieve is this:
when this script finished it should start again, and again, let's say like infinite loop, so click on the button, close, open URL again, close, and so on:

I am new to Python and I try something like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

while True:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = "https://example.org/"
    driver.get(url)
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cool-button")
    button.click()
    driver.quit()
```

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Comment: But why do you need to quit the driver?

Comment: @Prophet, because the click is saved to localStorage and I think is easier to quit and start again f you know what I mean, or if it easier to clear all inside localStorage

Comment: OK, maybe I don't understand the point. So, why not just do `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` to initialize the driver from beginning each time as you already wrote?

Comment: what is wrong with your current code?  It works fine for me, I changed it to google.com and it just kept opening it/closing it over and over and over.....not sure why you would want to do that, but it does work

Comment: @JD2775 : yes even it works for me, I don't see any issue.

Comment: @JD2775, I write above: "the click is saved to localStorage and I think is easier to quit and start again if you know what I mean"   driver = webdriver.Chrome() could be a solution.

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome() ` it is already there, how it could be the solution ?

Comment: @cruisepandey, yes, but when the script is clicked I run again driver = webdriver.Chrome()  to initialize the driver from the beginning

Comment: @mijok : Your code on my machine works just fine.

Comment: @mijok several users have come through and we still aren't sure *what is the problem with the code you have presented*? How is your code not acheiving what you want?

Answer (score 0):

We do the same thing here where we test when we want to attempt a "retry" of a test. One thing to note in your code above; you give no wait time for the "cool-button" to appear, become clickable or it's presence known; that will often lead to a failing result. I added support for that; as well as encompassed the entire code in an keyboard interrupted while loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


try:
    while True:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        url = "https://example.org/" 
        driver.get(url)
        try:
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "cool-button")))
            button.click()
        except:
            print('could not find the "cool" button')
            pass
        driver.quit()
        print("Press CTRL+C to escape!")
        time.sleep(3)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    quit()
```

I'd also suggest this youtube as a very good resource on the topic of selenium:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5jt2bhSeXs